# Is there such usage as verb+ing verb+ing somebody?

Tags: grammaticality-in-context

It is a comment describing the [anime](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Qn0uIvH0QE4) that I saw:

> "WHILE **TAKING RESTRAINING OUR PRISONER MORGAN**, HE MANAGED TO SLICE AND
>   KILL GARP-SAN!"

Is this "taking restraining" a valid usage?

Comment: no there is nothing like that, as far as I know at least. maybe there was a spelling error?

Comment: Please don't use ALL CAPS.  It makes it seem like you are SHOUTING.

Comment: @Jasper it's a direct quote from [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Qn0uIvH0QE4). I'm guessing that it should only read "taking" **or** "restraining".

Comment: It is customary to include an actual question in the Body of your Question.

Comment: It looks like a careless omission to me. It should say "While taking **and** restraining our prisoner..."

Comment: Is it possibly meant to be something like  "placing in restraints", i.e. "handcuffing"?  "slice" gets a chuckle.

Comment: I wonder who deleted ***my*** comments (not the first time) while leaving others.

Answer (score 1):

Whether it's a "valid" usage is up for debate, I suppose, but it looks to me like the translators omitted a conjunction:

> While taking **and** restraining our prisoner Morgan, he managed to slice and kill Garp-San.

In other words, while Morgan was being *taken and restrained* – or perhaps we could say, while Morgan was being *arrested* – Garp-San was killed by a sword.

Using two verbs with a conjunction such as *and* is quite common in English. For example:

> - Mr White hurt his neck while [restraining and controlling](http://www.pensions-ombudsman.org.uk/wp-content/uploads/p00925.doc) the prisoner.
> - Leash dogs while [entering and exiting](http://www.dogparkfriends.org/tips) the dog park.

In fact, nothing limits us to just two verbs; we could use three or more:

> Include signs that remind everyone to wash hands before [eating, drinking, or preparing food](https://books.google.com/books?id=TQ_uAQAAQBAJ&pg=PA94&dq=%22wash%20hands%20before%20eating%20drinking%20or%20preparing%22&hl=en&sa=X).

This really looks like a missing word, and I'd strongly advise **against** doing this without a conjunction:

> <strike>Mr White hurt his neck while restraining controlling the prisoner</strike>.

Answer (score -1):

There is certainly a completely grammatically correct form of two gerunds adjacent in a sentence:

> He sighed **starting cleaning** the floor.
>   We had such fun **opening nesting** dolls!
>   **Spreading growing** branches wider and wider the oak reigned over the forest.

Yes, it is possible to amend those examples to add an article or a pronoun between the gerunds, but it's not required.

Comment: That first one sounds quite awkward to me. _He sighed, and started to clean the floor. He sighed, starting to clean the floor._ Those would be much better. As for #2, that's a valid sentence, but it's not the same construct – _nesting_ functions adjectively there, much like _dancing_ in _dancing lessons_. The third one isn't exemplary English, either; I feel it needs a conjunction and a comma: _Spreading and growing its branches wider and wider, the oak tree reigned over the forest._.

Comment: still don't get it...it makes me confused more..

Comment: The third one I'd probably put as "Spreading ***his*** growing...".  The first we could write, "Bending low and starting cleaning the floor, he sighed" (and yes, "starting to clean" is essentially the same, does not make mine non-grammatical, though).

Comment: It may not be non-grammatical, but it still sounds [horrific at best](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/67875/starting-cleaning-vs-starting-to-clean), and would best be avoided.

Comment: The problem I have with this answer is that it would lead the learner to believe that there's no problem with the cartoon's translation. You seem to be validating the construct. There may be places where it happens, but the O.P.'s example is more likely a typo than a complex grammar structure. Words like "certainly completely correct" don't really answer this particular question very well.